# Reload page after function execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple javascript code like below and I'd like to reload page after fadeOut and fadeIn fileds but I don't know where should I put `window.location.reload();` function.  Do You have any suggestions ? I'm new in JavaScript.

```
    <script>$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.updateButton').on('click', function() {
        var member_id = $(this).attr('member_id');
        var city = $('#city'+member_id).val();
        var continent = $('#continent'+member_id).val();
        var country = $('#country'+member_id).val();
        var id = $('#id'+member_id).val();

        req = $.ajax({
            url : '/deleteRequest',
            type : 'POST',
            data :
                {city : city,continent : continent,country : country,id : id}
        });
        req.done(function(data) {
            $('#city'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
            $('#continent'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
            $('#country'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
            $('#id'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
             });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: in the done function usualy

Comment: end of the req done function, maybe setTimeout("window.location.reload()",2000); is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated code that you can have a look and try. I have merged all your elements and `fadeIn` has a callback, where you can refresh your page. So the page will reloaded only when the `fadeIn` is completed:

```
$('#city' + member_id + ',#continent' + member_id + ', #country' + member_id + ', #id' + member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should try

```
req.always(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

it will work always whether you get resonse or not.if you want to reload when you get response you can check out tutorial [here](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds).

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a timeout function

```
  req.done(function(data) {
                    $('#city'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
                    $('#continent'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
                    $('#country'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
                    $('#id'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
                     setTimeout(function(){
                     window.location.reload();
                       },TotalTimeNeededbyThheAnimationInmiliseconds)
                     });

            });
```

Comment: `windows.location.href()` isn't a function. Do you mean `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: i didnt oceded it rightly  its just a view point for you use your code there man

Answer (score 1):

```
req.done(function(data) {
        $('#city'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        $('#continent'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        $('#country'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        $('#id'+member_id).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        window.location = '';  // This will reload your page.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in latest jquery

Deprecation Notice:

> ```
> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their
> ```
>
> eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always()
>   instead.
>
> use `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` instead of `success()`, `error()` and
>   `complete()`.

i believe you want to fade and hide only on ajax success so you are placing it in `done()`.

if you want to reload everytime the ajax finishes use `always()`

eg :

```
req.always(function(){
   window.location.reload(false); 
// If we needed to pull the document from
//  the web-server again (such as where the document contents
//  change dynamically) we would pass the argument as 'true'.
});
```

or

if you want it both in `done()` 
then

```
req.done(function(){
 // you fadein,fadeout code 

window.location.reload();
});
```